# How to solve ImportError: No module named web3?

Tags: web3.py

I already installed web3 using pip install, but I get the error "ImportError: No module named web3" when I try to use it.

Comment: As far as I know pip is a tool for installing and managing Python packages and hence your question might be about `web3py`, but instead in the tag I see `web3js`.

Comment: Can you post the results of `pip freeze`?

Answer (score 2):

Without your source code, it's hard to say exactly what's going wrong. However, you might have mismatched `pip` and `python` if your environment already has Python 2 installed and you're attempting to use Python 3.

If I `pip install web3` and then create a file with the following contents:

```
import json
import web3

from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, TestRPCProvider
```

I don't have any problems with it on macOS with Python 3:

```
$ pip --version

pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ python --version

Python 3.6.4
```

You might consider looking into [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) so that you can have a clean Python environment each time you want to work with it. This can also help ensure you have isolation between Python versions and pip installs.